# Find the Count of a property for a particular condition in Table in Big Query

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a table which has many properties in Big Query. I am concerned with two properties of the Big Query.

I have

> hits.eCommerceAction.action_type , hits.product.productSKU and hits.hitNumber.

Have written the following code

```
SELECT hits.product.productSKU as SKU,
IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1', (hits.hitNumber), NULL) ListCLicks 
IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2', (hits.hitNumber), NULL)) PDV
FROM [107485206.ga_sessions_20160101]
where hits.eCommerceAction.action_type in ('1')
#group by SKU,ListClicks
```

My problem is that the above code returns the first value of hits.hitNumber which is a index number for a SKU. A SKU can have multiple hits.hitNumber. I want to count(not sum as it a index) the total hits.hitNumber for SKU.

```
ProductSKU | PDV | ListCLicks
-------------------------
1          | 120 |  235 
2          | 234 |  124 
3          | 2311|  1256
4          | 12  |  34
5          | 12  |  33
2          | 112 |  345
4          | 789 |  1110
2          | 3333|  2131
```

PDV is hits.hitNumber index when hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'and 
List Clicks is hits.hitNumber index when hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1'

And the Output is

```
ProductSKU | PDV | ListCLicks
-------------------------
1          | 1   |  1   
2          | 3   |  3   
3          | 1   |  1
4          | 2   |  2
5          | 1   |  1
```

PDV is hits.hitNumber count when hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2'and 
List Clicks is hits.hitNumber count when hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1'

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not totally clear what exactly your case is. You should provide some simplified input example and expected output

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have added the same. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to count the number of ecommerce actions by type.  If so, you can accomplish this with a `SUM` that adds 1 per relevant action, and 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT hits.product.productSKU as SKU,
  SUM(IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '1', 1, 0)) ListCLicks, 
  SUM(IF(hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = '2', 1, 0)) PDV
FROM [107485206.ga_sessions_20160101]
GROUP BY SKU
```